# CSS Flexbox Styling issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement flex-boxes onto one of my sub-pages for my website. Every-time I select `flex-direction: row;` the columns/flex-boxes just all display down the size of the web-page instead of display across the web-page as I am trying to intend.

**CSS**

```
}
/*========================TUTORIAL START========================*/
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
}
.card-content {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #b8860b;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1.25em 1.25em 0.3em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em){
  .card { width: 50%; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
  .card { width: 33.33%; }

/*========================TUTORIAL END========================*/
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- HTML STARTS -->
<!--HEADER STARTS-->
<!-- MAIN HTML HEAD -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<!-- MAIN HTML HEAD -->
<!--HEADER ENDS-->
<!-- NAV BAR STARTS -->
                <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tutorial.html">Guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
<!-- NAV BAR ENDS -->
        <div id="wrapper">
        <!--BANNER STARTS-->
            <header class="banner">
                <h2>Guide</h2>
                <h5>Creating a website in HTML</h5> 
                <h5><i>(Learning a new study skill)</i></h5>
                <br>
                <br>
            </header>
            <!--BANNER ENDS-->
            <main>
<!-- PAGE CONTENTS ARTICLE STARTS -->
                <article>
                <div class="instructions">
                <h2>Creating a website using HTML & CSS</h2>
                <h5>In this simple 6 step tutorial, I will demonstrate how to create a simple web-page using only HTML & CSS. The reason for choosing this tutorial is because I have recently learnt about website development as a new study skill.</h5>
                <br>
                <ol class="cards">
                <ol class"media"> 
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 1: Choosing a text editor</h3>
                    <img src="images/step1.jpg" alt="Step 1">
                    <p>Open a text editor like Notepad or VS Code to begin creating your webpage.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 2: Creating index.html</h3>
                    <img src="images/step2.png" alt="Step 2">
                    <p>In the text editor, create a new file and save it as "index.html" for your main HTML content and web-page.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 3: HTML Page Structure</h3>
                    <img src="images/step3.png" alt="Step 3">
                    <p>Inside "index.html," use HTML tags like "html", "head", and "body" to structure the webpage. Its up to you what additional content you would like to add, just ensure the basic structure is applied.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 4: Creating the Stylesheet</h3>
                    <img src="images/step4.png" alt="Step 4">
                    <p>Now, create another file in the text editor and save it as "styles.css" to handle styling for the HTML webpage.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 5: Linking CSS to Index page</h3>
                    <img src="images/step5.jpg" alt="Step 5">
                    <p>Link "styles.css" to "index.html" by using the "link" tag in the "head" section. This step is crucial in order to correctly link your web-page and introduce styling techniques.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
                    <li class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <h3>Step 6: Adding content to HTML & Stylesheet</h3>
                    <img src="images/step6.jpg" alt="Step 6">
                    <p>Design and customise your webpage in "index.html" and "styles.css" to bring your web design vision to life. Save and preview your creation. Its best to view your creation on a web-browser, with Google Chrome being recommended for testing and previewing. It's now entirely up to you on what content and styling techniques you wish to add to your web-page.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </li>
       </ol>    <!--Close the list-->
</div>  <!--Close the tutorial instructions container div-->
                </article>
            </main>
<!-- PAGE CONTENTS ARTICLE ENDS -->
            <!-- FOOTER STARTS -->
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2023, author.</p>
                <a href=""></a><b>Email (university@email)</b></footer>
            <!-- FOOTER ENDS -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- HTML ENDS -->
```

I wish for the flex-boxes to displayed in a horizontal way, displaying across the web-page and not displayed vertical running down the side of the web-page. Thank you! Any questions, just ask.

Comment: You open *two*  `ol` elements, but only close *one* , also in the second opening `ol` there is an "=" missing after "class"

Comment: which section of the code is this </ol>, I cant see it flagged in my validator.

Comment: What validator are you using, that would not flag `<ol class="cards"><ol class"media">` as an error? You can not have a `ol` as a child of another `ol`.

Answer (score -1):

to layout the elements within a card-content div horizontally add { display: 'flex' } i.e

```
.card-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #b8860b;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1.25em 1.25em 0.3em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/misty-tdd-wnjntw

Comment: That just gives me more errors. 

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/2fb5daa11f8b77ccc140fca6575fae8e

Comment: @ArunDray can you describe how this doesn't fit your question? it seems to me that your goal was to have the card content laid out horizontally and thats what your image shows

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood. They are currently displayed **vertically**, I wish for them to be **horizontal**, running across the page and not down the page.